# Static block not working

Tags: magento2

In my product page, static block is set properly but its now showing up images attached to it. link - http://kiabzanew.site/index.php/new-arrivals/pink-republic-top.html

pls check SS

[image: Product page]

[image: static Block]

Comment: you can try to check in here http://kiabzanew.site/index.php/pub/media/wysiwyg/4_2.png

Comment: Yes i check there & the icons are there in the folder

Comment: @Patrik problem is index.php in base url

Answer (score 1):

> Actual problem is index.php in URL

You can remove index.php in baseurl's on this path `Stores > Configuration > General > Web` from `http://kiabzanew.site/index.php/` to `http://kiabzanew.site/`

And enable `Use Web Server Rewrites > YES`

Then renindex all & flush the cache.

Comment: its saved as http://kiabzanew.site/ already... still its catching http://kiabzanew.site/index.php

Comment: fixed it by enabling ,Use Web Server Rewrites > YES